# Apply formula to cells with data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Is it possible to apply a formula to cells with data without using macros?

For example, user enters "A3 A6 A8" in a cell, and then it applies UDF  "CONCATENATEREF()" to that cell that gets those reference values and concatenates them using "/" as separators

I need this to be very user friendly and having to setup to enable macros wouldn't be

I know this can be done manually but the users are somewhat non tech savvy

Comment: No, it's not possible, you can't have both value / text in the same cell.

Comment: Nope, but you could create a macro that takes input